# No overload for method 'select' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i'm trying to get two values from my query but i get this error:

"No overload for method 'select' takes 2 arguments"

Here is my code:

```
    public class myType
    {
        public long anId{ get; set; }
        public float aCost{ get; set; }
    }

    IEnumerable<myType> result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(p => p["Id"]).Select(a => a["Id"], t => t.Sum(p => p["Cost"].ToFloat()));
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
.Select(a => new myType 
            { 
               anId = a.Key, 
               aCost = a.Sum(p => p["Cost"].ToFloat())
            })
```